# Fibonacci sequence divisible by 7?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, fibonacci-numbers

> Make and prove a conjecture about when the Fibonacci sequence, $F_n$, is divisible by $7$.

I've realized it's when $n$ is a multiple of $8$. I just don't know how to go about proving it.

Answer (score 18):

Look at the sequence $F_n$ reduced mod $7$:

```
1,1,2,3,5,1,6,0,6,6,5,4,2,6,1,0, 1,1,2.. and it repeats forever
```

Since the only places where it is 0 are $n=8,16$ this proves that $7|F_n \iff 8|n$.

---

General theory of recurrence relations.

**Definition** A $k$th order recurrence relation on some set $X$ is a function $a : \mathbb N \rightarrow X$ with $k$ initial values i.e. $a(1),\cdots,a(k)$ defined and for all $i > k$, $a(i+k+1) = f(a(i),a(i+1),\cdots,a(i+k))$. Note that a $k$th order recurrence is also a $k+1$th order recurrence.

**Notation** We generally write the elements of a $k$th order recurrence relation as $(a_n)$.

**Definition** Recurrence relation homomorphisms, let $(a_n)$ be a $k$th order recurrence relation on the set $X$ defined by the map $f : X^k \rightarrow X$ (as well as some initial values). A map $\varphi : X -> Y$ is called a recurrence relation homomorphism on $a$ when there exists $f' : Y^k \rightarrow Y$ satisfying the commutative diagram $\varphi \circ f = f' \circ \varphi$.

**Theorem** Recurrence relation homomorphisms produce recurrence relations. Suppose we are given a recurrence relation homomorphism in the notation above. The claim is that $b_n = \varphi(a_n)$ is also a $k$th order recurrence relation.

**Proof** Clearly $k$ initial values are given, further for $i > k$ we have $b_{i+k+1} = \varphi(f(a_{i},a_{i+1},\cdots,a_{i+k})) = f'(\varphi(a_{i}),\varphi(a_{i+1}),\cdots,\varphi(a_{i+k}))) = f'(b_{i},b_{i+1},\cdots,b_{i+k}).$

**Example** The "reduction mod m" map $\varphi : \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$ as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33431/subtraction-and-division-with-integers-modulo-3/33435#33435) is a recurrence homomorphism on any recurrence defined by a polynomial. To see this note that homomorphisms on rings (such as $\varphi$) can be lifted to homomorphisms on polynomial rings over the respective rings. That induces the map from $f$ to $f'$.

**Example** Call the Fibonacci sequence $(F_n)$ reduced mod 7: $(S_n)$, this is a recurrence by the general example above. Note that $F_n \equiv S_n \pmod 7$.

**Theorem** Initial segments may be discarded. Suppose $a_n$ is a recurrence relation of order $k$, then $b_n = a_{n+h}$ for any constant $h$ is also a recurrence relation of order $k$.

**Proof** Initial values are computed easily, if $f$ is the function defining elements of $a$ then $f$ also defines elements of $b$, to see this note that for $i > k$ we have $b_i = a_{i+h} = f(a_{i+h},a_{i+1+h},\cdots,a_{i+k+h}) = f(b_{i},b_{i+1},\cdots,b_{i+k})$.

**Theorem** Periodicity. Suppose the recurrence relation $b_n$ is defined as $a_{n+h}$ (both being $k$th order), if they share the first $k$ initial values then they are equal everywhere.

**Proof** Induction on $n$ in the stronger proposition that for all $i \le n$, $a_i = b_i$.

- base case (n = k): This is the hypothesis of the theorem.
- recursive step ($n \implies n+1$): Since for every $i \le n$, $a_i = b_i$ we have $a_{n+1} = f(a_{n-k},a_{n-k+1},\cdots,a_{n}) = f(b_{n-k},b_{n-k+1},\cdots,b_{n}) = b_{n+1}$ (since they are both defined by $f$).

**Example** Define $S'_n = S_{n+16}$ they share the first two initial values therefore they are equal everywhere.

**Example** Define $S_n^r = S_{n+16\cdot r}$ by induction these are all equal: The base case $r=0$ is trivial and the recursive step $r \implies r+1$ comes form an adaptation of the previous example and transitivity.

**Theorem** $7|F_n \iff 8|n$.

**Proof** By the previous examples we have seen that $F_n \equiv F_{n+16\cdot r} \pmod 7$, furthermore a direct computation of the first 16 values of $S_n$ (at the top) shows that $F_n \equiv 0 \pmod 7 \iff n = 0+16 \cdot r,8+16\cdot r$ this is equivalent to $8|n$ and $x = 0 \pmod m$ is equivalent to $m|x$.

Comment: It's the right observation but there's no proof here.

Comment: @lhf, in my mind this is rigorous proof. Please tell me what your objection is in case I have a gap in my argument.

Comment: I'd be happier with an induction but I see now that you've listed the whole sequence mod 7 until a cycle appears, so it's ok.

Comment: @quanta: _As it's written_, I wouldn't call it a rigorous proof (in a homework assignment, I wouldn't give _full_ points), but if I was talking to a college, I wouldn't want him to tell me more, so in this sense it's indeed complete.

Comment: @Hendrik, Why don't you think that's a rigorous and complete proof?

Comment: I am implicitly using several lemmas and constructions such as modular arithmetic, relation between modular arithmetic and divisibility... maybe I use a theorem or construction which you are not familiar with?

Comment: @quanta: Because you didn't explicitly write _why_ it repeats forever. I'm pretty sure you fully understand what you're writing in your answer, and I gave you +1 for it since it's the easiest (and hence best) answer here, but I can't look into your mind and see if you _really_ understand everything: If you were a student of mine whom I don't know well, I'd subtract a point; if you were a studied mathematician, I'd expect exactly the answer you gave above and no more.

Comment: @quanta: Ah, just found your other comment: No no, I'm familiar with the stuff needed.

Comment: This is a proof. albeit "it repeats forever" should be by induction/.

Comment: @Hendrik I have to agree with you.  This post was obviously made by someone looking for help with homework, **or** studying some textbook alone without much help.  In either case, it would be beneficial to completely justify the statement "and it repeats forever" in the answer itself.

Comment: @Hendrik, I guess you are thinking about things as a teacher. I wrote the proof so that *other people* would understand it. It's not written to prove to someone that I understand it. Anyway I have filled the details now.

Comment: @picakhu, I have added a couple of explicit examples of induction but they are so trivial I generally expect readers to formulate and prove them in their heads.

Comment: @quanta: Wow, I certainly _didn't_ expect you to fill _so many_ details. As for your last comment, I'm thinking _both_ as a researcher and a scientist. As a researcher, I was perfectly happy with your original answer (so I upvoted it since I thought "ah, that makes is clear", not "this is a rigorous proof"), but I wanted to point out that someone who just starts learning these things _really_ shouldn't think that this was a _complete rigorous_ proof. The meaning of "complete rigorous" of course depends _very much_ on your level of knowledge.

Comment: @quanta Very useful for the beginner: +1

Comment: Should be an easy exercise in induction if you use some standard Fibonacci relations.

Answer (score 11):

A more pedestrian approach of induction, looking at the first 16 fibonacci numbers, the only 2 which are divisible by 7 are $f_8=21$ and $f_{16}=987$. Conjecture that $f_n$ is divisible by 7 if and only if $n$ is divisible by 8, as you mention in the comments. Using these observations as the base case, assume the result holds for all $f_j$ for $j\leq n$. Notice

$$
f_{n+1}=21f_{n-6}+13f_{n-7}
$$

which can be worked out by continually applying the recursive definition of the fibonacci sequence. This equation makes the induction follow pretty easily.

Comment: Alternatelly one can use the $F$ matrix $(1 1 \\ 1 0)$ and check it's 8'th power. The first row gives your relation, anyhow the entire matrix is $(f_8 f_7 \\ f_7 f_6)$ which mod 7 is $(-1 0 \\ 0 1 )$.

Comment: @user9176 Note that your matrix is simply the matrix form of the shift map mentioned in my answer. Here linearity is in fact irrelevant. All that matters is that the shift map is invertible, so a permutation, so its orbits are cycles; e.g. see the *nonlinear* recursion in my answer.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint** $ $ The shift map $\rm\:n\to n+1\:$ on pairs $\rm\:(f_{n-1},\:f_n)\,\ \ (mod\ 7)\,$ is an invertible map on a finite set, so is a *permutation*, so its orbits are *cycles*.  Below is a further hint from one of my old sci.math posts.  See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4758/why-do-primes-other-than-2-and-5-divide-infinitely-many-repunits/4810#4810) for much  more.

---

> A sequence f(n) satisfies the relation $\rm\,f(n+2) = f(n+1)^2 - f(n),\,$ with $\rm \,f(1) = 39\,$ and $\rm \,f(2) = 45.\,$  Prove that $1986$ divides infinitely 
>   many terms of the sequence.

Since the recursion determines unique values $\rm\:f_{n+2},\:f_n\:$ when 
    run fore/backward, the shift map on the sequence induces a *permutation* $\rm\:F\:$ on integer pairs 
    $$\rm mod\  1986\!:\ \ F(f_n,f_{n+1})\ =\ (f_{n+1},f_{n+2})\ \quad i.e.\quad  F(a,b)\: =\ (b,\,b^2-a)\ \ $$
    But $\:0\:$ occurs in the cycle containing $(39,45)$ since $\rm\:F(39,45)\: =\: (45,0),\:$ 
    so  $\:0\:$ occurs infinitely often in this finite cycle when $\rm\:F\:$ is iterated.

This replaces less formal arguments elsewhere on "repeated blocks" 
    by  rigorous arguments on standard structures (permutations and 
    their cycle decomposition), thus clarifying the essence of the matter. 
    One should strive to learn to recognize these abstractions in the wild, 
    else one will be doomed to continually reinvent the wheel (here cycle).

Comment: Wouldn't you also need to prove that $F^{\text{something}}(39,45) = (39,45)$?

Comment: @quanta Since $\rm\:F\:$ is permutation its orbits are *cycles*. That's the key point. In that sci.math thread other folks where proving this from scratch "reinventing the wheel (cycle)".

Comment: How is it seen that F is a permutation?

Comment: @quanta: Hint: it's an invertible map on a finite set - see the sentence that begins "Simpler".

Answer (score 1):

There is a cool thing with the Fibonacci and number 7, it transforms to a sequence of 16 number that repeat infinitely.

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

0,1,1,2,3,5,1,6,0,6,6,5,4,2,6,1,0

If you keep with the sequence you can see there is a 0 every 8th position so this let us with two slices of sequence.

s1 : 1,1,2,3,5,1,6
   s2 : 6,6,5,4,2,6,1

So finobacci in module 7 will be like: 0s10s20s10s2........

If you take a consecutive s1 , s2 and add them number by number:

```
s1 : 1,1,2,3,5,1,6

s2 : 6,6,5,4,2,6,1 +

     7,7,7,7,7,7,7
```

Which in module 7 is 0 so Fibonacci is transformed into a sequence of infinite 0.

So the process will be the following:
1. Module 7 to Fibonacci sequence.

0,1,1,2,3,5,1,6,0,6,6,5,4,2,6,1,0,1,1,2,3,5,1,6,0,6,6,5,4,2,6,1,0,1,1,2,3,5,1,6,0,6,6,5,4,2,6,1,0....

2. Group them by groups of 8 numbers.
3. If you take all groups of s1 and add them with their respective s2, consecutive. The result should be an infinite sequence of 0.

Answer (score 0):

The Fibonacci sequence is a special case of the more general family of Lucas sequences. Hence, the theory pertaining to the Lucas and companion Lucas sequences necessarily applies to the Fibonacci sequence.

That being said, the first place that $7$ divides the $F_{n}$ sequence is when $n = 8$. Hence, the "rank of apparition'' of $7$ in the $F_{n}$ sequence is $8$. That is, $\omega(7) = 8$. Moreover, for Lucas sequences, and thus for the Fibonacci sequence, a prime $p$ divides the Fibonacci sequence at a term, $F_{k}$ if and only if $k$ is some multiple of $\omega(p)$; that is, $p$ divides every term and only those terms of the said sequence whose index $k = m\omega(p),$ for every positive integer $m$. Hence, the only terms of the Fibonacci sequence that contain $7$ as a factor are

$$ F_{8}, F_{16}, F_{24}, \ldots.$$