# Are cyclic group generators guaranteed to keep generating all group elements, and why?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

A cyclic group is a group that can be generated by repeatedly applying the group operation to an element of the group called the "generator".

I noticed that, at least for the multiplicative group of integers modulo $5$, the equations $x = 2^y \pmod{5}$ and $x = 3^y \pmod{5}$, where $x$ is any element of said group, both have infinite solutions. $2$ and $3$ are generators of this group.

Ascending powers of either generator modulo 5 produce a unique, endless pattern.
For example:

$$2^1\pmod{5} = 2$$

$$2^2\pmod{5}= 4$$

$$2^3\pmod{5} = 3$$

$$2^4\pmod{5} = 1$$

$$2^5\pmod{5} = 2$$

$$2^6\pmod{5}= 4$$

$$2^7\pmod{5}= 3$$

The repeating pattern contains all the elements of the group.

Is there a proof that any cyclic group generator produces an endlessly repeating pattern containing all elements of its group?

EDIT: I just realized what I'm asking is answered here: [Why does a number like $2^n\bmod 7$ have a repeating pattern?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301247/why-does-a-number-like-2n-bmod-7-have-a-repeating-pattern)

Comment: Yes.  You can prove it with long division in the exponent.  It's also obvious because you have an infinite number of exponents but only finitely many group elements.

Comment: In finite groups, as the tag says though not the question, the pigeonhole principle guarantees this, otherwise you would run out of elements to assign $a^n$ to

Comment: Note also that $5$ is a prime and there is always a primitive root for a prime $p$ ie a number whose powers will cycle all the non-zero integers less than $p$. Not every number does this, and the existence of a primitive root is equivalent to saying that the multiplicative group of residues modulo a prime is always cyclic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

For all generators $a$ of a cyclic group $G$, for each $g\in G$, there exists an $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $a^n=g$ by definition of $G$ being cyclic; that includes letting $g$ be another generator. For finite groups, it follows from the Pigeonhole Principle. For the only infinite cyclic group, $(\Bbb Z, +)$, up to isomorphism, the generator is either $1$ or $-1$, each of which generates each element as a multiple.