# Find the remainder of the following

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Given that
 $F(1)=1,F(2)=1$ and $F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2)$ , $n>2$ for this series, now if $f(n)$ is the remainder if $F(n)$  is divided by $5$  then the value of $f(2000)$   is

1. 1
2. 0
3. 3
4. 2

For doing this it is obvious that problem is indicating the Fibonacci Series. Now we know that 
$n th$  term of Fibonacci series can be determined by the formula

$$[ (Phi)^n - (phi)^n ]/\sqrt 5 , Phi=(1+\sqrt5)/2 ,  phi=(1-\sqrt5)/2 $$

I dont no whether this is needed for this problem or not but I observed that $F(5)=5, F(10)=55, F(15)=610$ so I guess $F(2000)$ must be  divisible by 5 **so answer is 0**.

**I'm not satisfy with this and need better explanation or analytic solution. help me...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove your statement "$F(5)=5,F(10)=55,F(15)=610$ so I guess $F(2000)$ must be divisible by $5$ so answer is $0$", you may use mathematical induction to prove "$F(5n)$ is divisible by $5$".

The base case, $F(5) = 5$, is true.

Assume the case $n = k$ is true, therefore we can write $F(5k) = 5p$ for some positive integer $k$ and $p$, now for $n = k+1,$

$F(5(k+1)) = F(5k+5) = F(5k+4) + F(5k+3) = 2 \times F(5k+3) + F(5k+2) $

$ = 2 \times (F(5k+2) + F(5k+1)) + F(5k+1) + F(5k) $

$ = 2 \times F(5k+2) + 3 \times F(5k+1) + F(5k) $

$ = 2 \times (F(5k+1) + F(5k)) + 3 \times F(5k+1) + F(5k) $

$ = 5 \times F(5k+1) + 3 \times F(5k) $

$ = 5 \times F(5k+1) + 15p$

$ = 5 \times (F(5k+1) + 3p)$

Hence by mathematical induction, $F(5n)$ is divisible by $5$ for all positive integers $n$.

From the proof, you can also see that $F(n+5) = 5\times F(n+1) + 3\times F(n)$. Therefore if $F(n)$ is divisible by 5, so is $F(n+5)$. Applying this repeatedly you will get $F(n)$ is divisible by $5$ when $n$ is divisible by $5$. This is a simple explanation of your observation.

Comment: Nice and rigorous!

Answer (score 0):

From [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Divisibility_properties), $F_{5m}$ is divisible by $F_5=5$ where $m$ is any integer

**See also** : [on the divisibility properties of fibonacci numbers](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/4-3/halton.pdf)
and  [Fibonacci GCD](https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/20004.5.shtml)

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/60353/242) for proofs of these divisibility properties of Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Don't you think that a link-only answer like this should be a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Compute the recurrence, $\bmod5$. As there are just $25$ possible pairs of input values, you quickly find the period.

$$\color{blue}{1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 3, 1, 4, 0, 4, 4, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 4, 1, 0,} 1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 3, 1, 4, 0, \cdots$$

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/34795/242) for more on why it is periodic.